# Где проходят границы транзакций в DDD

Tags: java, ddd, транзакции

В каком слое архитектуры DDD следует располагать код управления транзакциями? Есть ли какие-либо рекомендации и best-practies на этот счет?

На данный момент я располагаю код управления транзакциями в репозиториях - внутри каждого метода репозитория располагается код отвечающий за открытие и закрытие транзакции.

Answer (score 0):

У вас неправильно проходит граница транзакций. Контроль целостности и бизнес-правил в DDD делается на уровне агрегата. Операция выглядит так:

1. читаем агрегат из репозитория
2. выполняем операцию над агрегатом
3. сохраняем агрегат в репозиторий

Вот эти три действия должны выполнятся в одной транзакции. Этот код находится в слое приложения (Application Layer). Т.е. есть класс типа:

```
class AccountApp {
  public void topUpAccount(Long accountId, Long amount) {
     AccountAggregate account = accountRepository.get(accountId);
     account.topUp(amount);
     accountRepository.save(account);
  }
}
```

Метод `topUpAccount` должен выполнятся в одной транзакции. Обратите внимание, что слой бизнес-логики в данном случае это только `AccountAggregate` (сам метод `topUp` может быть довольно сложным и использовать другие сущности из агрегата Account). И `AccountAggregate` ничего не знает ни о том:

1. когда транзакция начинается/заканчивается
2. как именно реализована транзакция

В идеале сама демаркация транзакций должна быть в слое приложения, а реализация отдельно (в слое инфраструктуры).

Вот пример того, как это делается в spring:

```
class AccountApp {
  @Transactional
  public void topUpAccount(Long accountId, Long amount) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Тут `@Transactional` обозначает, что метод `topUpAccount` будет выполнятся в транзакции. Как именно это делается, даже класс `AccountApp` не знает (не говоря уже об слое домена). Собственно реализация транзакций находится в сгенерированном прокси, который оборачивает вызовы к `topUpAccount`. Этот прокси умеет взаимодействовать в repository определенным образом (обычно через паттерн UnitOfWork).

Comment: Уточню, что речь идет о коде реализующим транзакции. Просто этот код сильно зависит от способа доступа к данным, и не хотелось бы, чтобы бизнес логика зависела от таких деталей. P.s. вопрос - вы относите интерфейсы репозиториев к слою бизнес логики?

Comment: Бизнес логика не зависит от таких деталей. Репозитории не являются частью бизнес логики, они как раз нужны, чтоб отделить бизнес логику от деталей того, как сущности хранятся. Я добавил необходимые пояснения.

Comment: С удовольствием выслушаю мнение минусующих в комментариях. С чем не согласны? Поделитесь мнениями.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Если я правильно понял, то класс AccountApp принадлежит слою бизнес логики. И тогда у меня вопрос к такому подходу: что вообще поменяется, если транзакция будет реализована в методе save() класса AccountRepository? И ещё, использование анотаций для транзакций создает зависимость слоя бизнес логики от слоя доступа к данным (что произойдет, если для доступа к данным я захочу использовать JDBC?).

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли. `AccountApp` - это не бизнес логика (в ответе это вроде отражено, но верятно, нужно сильнее акцентировать внимание). Бизнес-логика только в `AccountAggregate`. AccountApp - это слой приложения (application layer).

Comment: В целом все верно написано, НО интерфейсы репозиториев относятся к слою БЛ.