# DDD как запускатьTransactions в Application Service?

Tags: php, проектирование, ddd

Как реализовывается запуск транзакций в Application Service?

Имеется структура:

```
src-
    - Module1
          - Application
               - BooService
               - FooService
          - Domain
             - Repository
                   - MyModelRepositoryInterface
          - Infrastructure
               - ExampleCommand
               - Repository
                   - MyModelRepository
    - Module2
          - Application
          - Domain
          - Infrastructure
```

Запускается выполнение команды \App\Module1\Infrastructure\ExampleCommand
который в свою очередь запускает сервис \App\Module1\Application\BooService
он обращается к репозиторию MyModelRepository и к сервису FooService получает какие то абстрактные данные и потом создаётся объект и сохраняется.

Каким образом реализовывается транзакция в этом сервисе? и вообще возможно ли она тут или нужно как то иначе архитектуру построить?
На ум приходит либо какой то сервис TransactionService на уровне Infrastructure с интерфейсом в Domain или работа через Events.

```
class BooService 
{
    public function execute()
    {

        //Transaction start
        
        $result = $this->fooService->execute();
        $this->myModelRepository->add(new MyModel($result->foo, $result->boo));

        //Transaction finish
        
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Смотрите тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1314014/218971

Comment: @RomanKonoval вроде просто описано, на моём примере можно комментарий оставить?